# How to end While Loop with correct answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, infinite-loop

Basically, my code will not 'end'. I know for sure there is something wrong with how I wrote my code, but I don't know where to fix or change. I've tried so many different things.

So this is my first time attempting to code a Guessing Game Challenge. 
I feel like I'm not quite understanding how to utilize the while loop, because no matter how many times I attempt to give a right answer, my game will not stop. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong? Many thanks.

```
#import random was used
answer = random.randint(1,101) #This is the answer for the specific game.
print(answer) #NEED TO DELETE THIS LINE AFTER Successful answer
print()
print()
print ("Enter a number!")
guess = int(input()) #Player guesses here.




while True:
    if guess == answer:
        print("YOU GOT THE ANSWER! WELL DONE")
        break

    elif guess <1 or guess > 100:
        print("OUT OF BOUNDS")
        break

    elif abs(guess - answer) <= 10 or abs(answer - guess) <= 10:
        print(input("WARM. YOU ARE GETTING CLOSER."))

    elif abs(guess - answer) > 10 or abs(answer - guess) > 10:
        print(input("COLD. TRY AGAIN."))

    else:
        print("ERROR")
```

Expected: I expected that when my guess integer == answer in different attempts, it would return to "YOU GOT THE ANSWER! WELL DONE!".
Actual: Even if I write the actual answer, the code just infinitely loops.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to put the part where you get input from the user inside the loop.

Comment: Yep, your break condition is never met, because you don't reassign your variable(guess).

Answer (score 1):

When you take an input in:

```
    elif abs(guess - answer) <= 10 or abs(answer - guess) <= 10:
         print(input("WARM. YOU ARE GETTING CLOSER."))
    elif abs(guess - answer) > 10 or abs(answer - guess) > 10:
         print(input("COLD. TRY AGAIN."))
```

You don't assign the input to variable *guess*, so it's always the value you input at the beginning and because of that the first answer given will be repeated in loop.

Change that fragment to:

```
elif abs(guess - answer) <= 10 or abs(answer - guess) <= 10:
    guess = int(input("WARM. YOU ARE GETTING CLOSER."))
elif abs(guess - answer) > 10 or abs(answer - guess) > 10:
    guess = int(input("COLD. TRY AGAIN."))
```

to reassign *guess* variable and it will work.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the big hint! Thank you so much for informing me to reassign the guess variable

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simplistic (not the most efficient one) to approach this:

```
cycle = True 
while cycle: 
    if guess == answer:
        print("YOU GOT THE ANSWER! WELL DONE")
        cycle = False

    elif guess <1 or guess > 100:
        print("OUT OF BOUNDS")
        cycle = False

    elif abs(guess - answer) <= 10 or abs(answer - guess) <= 10:
        print(input("WARM. YOU ARE GETTING CLOSER."))

    elif abs(guess - answer) > 10 or abs(answer - guess) > 10:
        print(input("COLD. TRY AGAIN."))

    else:
        print("ERROR")`
```